# Copy specific values from multiple excel files into one table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy 22 values from 400-something excelfiles and put the values in a specific format in the new sheet. All the values from the first file should end up on row 1 and their respective columns and all the values from file 2 on row 2 and so on.
I've tried getting VBA to open the source-files one by one and copy some of the data over using this method: https://www.encodedna.com/excel/read-multiple-excel-files-and-merge-data-to-single-file-using-vba.htm but I can't seem to get it work like I want to.

Do any of you have any good ideas or ways to copy ie H8, H9, H10 from each of the 400 sheets to one collective sheet. I don't need to loop from all of the rows and columns of the source file since I know the specific cels I need to copy. Hope you can help!

Comment: *"can't seem to get it work like I want to."* is no useful error description. Also instead of posting a link please show exactly what **you** tried and describe where you got errors or stuck. We cannot help you without seeing what your attempt was. See [ask]. Also give some example with data or screenshots how the result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the cells in the range you want copy from. Increment the target column after each copy, increment the target row after each file.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessFiles()

    ' specific cells to copy to colums 1 to 22
    Const RNG_COPY = "A10,A11,A3:H1,A2:H2,A3:F3"
    Const Folder = "C:\temp\so\" ' folder with multiple sheets
    Const SHT_OUT = "Sheet1" ' results sheet
 
    Dim FSO As Object, objFile, objFolder, SelectedFolder As String
    Dim wbIn As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsIn As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, r As Long, c As Integer
    
    ' select files to merge
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = Folder
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .Show
        SelectedFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Set objFolder = FSO.getFolder(SelectedFolder)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHT_OUT)
    r = 0 ' target row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFile.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
            Set wbIn = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path, True, True)
            Set wsIn = wbIn.Sheets(1)
    
            ' copy values to target row
            r = r + 1
            c = 1
            For Each cell In wsIn.Range(RNG_COPY).Cells
                ws.Cells(r, c) = cell
                c = c + 1
            Next
            wbIn.Close False
         End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox r & " files processed from " & SelectedFolder, vbInformation

End Sub
```